# Woocommerce sorting not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed last woocommerce plugin on my child theme.
When i change "Sort By" items on dropdown on shop page, nothing happend.
In Console view there is no any event.
JQuery works i check now,
jquery is loaded manually from footer.php like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also i add this in functions.php:

```
function my_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action('init', 'my_js');
```

Is there maybe sort with button and classic refresh?

EDIT:

this is footer.php where are scripts included:

```
<!-- JS Global Compulsory -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/smoothScroll.js"></script>
<!-- JS Customization -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<!-- JS Page Level -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
    });
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/placeholder-IE-fixes.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

header.php

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $BASE = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
?>

<?php $base = 'https://www.example.co'; ?>
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package parallax-one
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<?php parallax_hook_html_before(); ?>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
<!--<title>Example.co - Betting system builder</title>-->
<?php parallax_hook_head_top(); ?>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php parallax_hook_head_bottom(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?> 
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Web Fonts -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin'>

    <!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- CSS Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/theme-colors/blue.css"/>

    <!-- CSS Header and Footer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/headers/header-default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/footers/footer-v1.css">
    <script src="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/parallax-slider/css/parallax-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
    <!-- CSS Page Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/pages/pricing/pricing_v6.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/pages/pricing/pricing_v7.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/pages/pricing/pricing_v8.css">
    <!-- CSS Customization -->
    <!-- CSS Customization -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/custom.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base ?>/assets/css/pages/page_invoice.css">
</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" <?php body_class(); ?> 
    dir="<?php if (is_rtl()) echo "rtl"; else echo "ltr"; ?>">
 <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="logo" href="https://www.predictology.co">
                <img src="<?php $BASE ?>/assets/img/logo1-default.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <!-- End Logo -->

            <!-- Topbar -->
            <div class="topbar">
                <ul class="loginbar pull-right">
                    <li><a href="/pricing">Join Now</a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/benefits">Why Predictology?</a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/videos">Videos</a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/manual">User Guide</a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
                    <?php if($current_user->ID) { ?>
                    <li><a href="/wp/membership/"><?php echo $current_user->user_nicename; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="topbar-devider"></li> 
                    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                    <?php } else {?>
                    <li><a href="/wp/log-in">Login</a></li>
                    <?php } ?>  
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Topbar -->

            <!-- Toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- End Toggle -->
        </div><!--/end container-->

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mega-menu navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                           
                            <!-- Shortcodes -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="/predictions">
                                    Predictions
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Shortcodes -->                    

                            <!-- Misc Pages -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="/eloratings">
                                    Elo Ratings
                                </a>
                            </li>                          

                            <li>
                                <a href="/streaks">
                                    Streaks
                                </a>
                            </li>


                            <!-- Pages -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="/stats">
                                    Statististics
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Pages -->  

                            <!-- Pages -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="/bettrack">
                                    Bet Tracker
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Pages --> 

                            <li>
                            <a href="/pricing" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Join Now</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Misc Pages -->
                        <?php //wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'predictology-menu' ) ); ?>
                        </ul>
            </div><!--/end container-->
        </div><!--/navbar-collapse-->
```

Comment: That should be `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `init` but it should still work. I believe WooCommerce is probably enqueueing jquery anyway. I would switch to a default theme and test to try to isolate the problem. You may also want to try with just the parent theme. If the problem is the parent theme you should contact the theme author.

Comment: @helgatheviking It works when i switch to other theme. Problem is that i changed footer.php and header.php on my child theme.

Comment: @helgatheviking please check my code. When i switch on other theme and when i change sort by it refresh browser. So it looks like woocommerce does not use JQuery and AJAX. How is possible that this not work on my theme?

Comment: SOLVED ! I missed wp_footer() in footer.php.